# I proposed a flag to a question which was then deleted. Do I have to do something about it? Withdraw it somehow?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I've flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484922/how-do-i-emulate-classes-in-ecmascript-5) with the following comment:

> A similar question ([How can I emulate "classes" in JavaScript? (with or without a third-party library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355848/how-can-i-emulate-classes-in-javascript-with-or-without-a-third-party-librar)) was closed as not constructive, but I'm not sure how to mark this one as such and also not entirely sure if this one should be closed, too.

Some time after that, the question was deleted. (I don't know if that was done by the owner or by the moderators.)

Now I have a pending flag on that question. I don't understand whether the flag was helpful or not and also I don't know if I can somehow withdraw it so that it is not shown in my [flags summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3995261) page. ("Hey, the question is deleted, what's the point of the flag being pending?") The second question is the issue I'd like to get some help with.

Comment: It was deleted by the owner. Well, there's no more action needed from your side.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah, I see, thanks. But it would be nice to remove the flag from the flag summary (extra "pending" stuff is kind of annoying at times, they have orange labels :) ). Is it impossible for me to withdraw it?

Comment: You can't withdraw flags. It will slowly move out of sight over time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ right, thanks. This actually answers my question.

Comment: You probably flagged it with a mod-flag. Those flags are independent of whether the post is deleted or not. It will be processed by a mod somewhen (and probably declined, because closure is not worth a mod-flag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Other' flags aren't automatically dismissed when the question is deleted. There's no way to 'withdraw' flags.

A moderator would have gotten to it eventually, this post just sped up the process.

Comment: What's annoying about this is legitimate flags are sometimes invalidated by the time they are seen by a mod and you can't do anything about it. I flagged a question entirely composed of repeated "lorem ipsum" as abusive, but it was edited into better shape before the flag was handled.